# How to calculate the area of the region

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

defined by `(x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2)^2 <= x^2/k^2 - y^2/h^2 && x >= 0` assuming the parameters `a,b,h,k` positive?
Here is my try for concrete values of the parameters:

```
r = ImplicitRegion[
    (x^2/2^2 + y^2/1^2)^2 <= x^2/2 - y^2/3 && x >= 0,
    {x, y}
];
Area[r]
```

> Area::nmet: Unable to compute the area of region ImplicitRegion[(x^2/4+y^2)^2<=x^2/2-y^2/3&&x>=0,{x,y}].

The exact answer is preferable over a numeric one.

Comment: For a numeric answer, you can just use `N[Area[r]]`.

Comment: @Carl Woll: Thank you. It's funnily that Area[r, Method -> "NIntegrate"] does not work.

Comment: Also `Area@DiscretizeRegion[r, PrecisionGoal -> 8]`

Comment: Would a preliminary conversion to polar coordinates be an admissible solution?

Comment: @J. M.: Do you mean (x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2)^2 <= x^2/k^2 - y^2/h^2 /.{x->r Cos[\Phi],y->r  Sin[\Phi]}?

Comment: ...and then solve for `r^2`, yes, so that the usual area formula can be applied.

Comment: @J. M.: When realizing that idea, serious difficulties arise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we switch to the generalized polar coordinates by

```
ineq = FullSimplify[(x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2)^2 <= x^2/k^2 - y^2/h^2 /. 
{x -> a*r *Cos[\[Phi]], y -> b*r *Sin[\[Phi]]}]
```

> $$r^4\leq r^2 \left(\frac{a^2 \cos ^2(\phi )}{k^2}-\frac{b^2 \sin ^2(\phi )}{h^2}\right) $$

Next, we find $r$ through $\phi$:

```
Reduce[r^4 == (a^2 r^2 Cos[\[Phi]]^2)/k^2 - (b^2 r^2 Sin[\[Phi]]^2)/ h^2 && a > 0 && b > 0 
&& h > 0 && k > 0 && r >= 0 && \[Phi] > -Pi/2 && \[Phi] < Pi/2, r, Reals];
FullSimplify[%, Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0 && h > 0 && k > 0 && r >= 0 && 
\[Phi] > -Pi/2 && \[Phi] < Pi/2]
```

> (a == k r && [Phi] == 0) || 
>    r == 0 || ([Phi] != 0 && 
>      Sqrt[(a^2 Cos[[Phi]]^2)/k^2 - (b^2 Sin[[Phi]]^2)/h^2] == r && 
>      b k < a h Abs[Cot[[Phi]]])

Now we find the ends of the range of the integration by

```
FullSimplify[Reduce[r^4 == (a^2 r^2 Cos[\[Phi]]^2)/k^2 - (b^2 r^2 Sin[\[Phi]]^2)/
 h^2 && a > 0 && b > 0 && h > 0 && k > 0 &&
 r >= 0 && \[Phi] > -Pi/2 && \[Phi] < Pi/2, \[Phi], Reals]]
```

> a > 0 && b > 0 && h > 0 && 
>    k > 0 && ((a/k == r && [Phi] == 0) || (r == 0 && 
>        2 [Phi] < [Pi] && [Pi] + 2 [Phi] > 0) || (a/k > r && 
>        r >= 0 && ([Phi] == 
>           2 ArcTan[Sqrt[(
>             2 b^2 k^2 + 
>              h^2 (a^2 + 
>                 k (k r^2 - 
>                    2 Sqrt[((a^2 h^2 + b^2 k^2) (b^2 + h^2 r^2))/
>                     h^4])))/(h^2 (a - k r) (a + k r))]] || [Phi] + 
>            2 ArcTan[Sqrt[(
>              2 b^2 k^2 + 
>               h^2 (a^2 + 
>                  k (k r^2 - 
>                     2 Sqrt[((a^2 h^2 + b^2 k^2) (b^2 + h^2 r^2))/
>                      h^4])))/(h^2 (a - k r) (a + k r))]] == 0)))

```
2 ArcTan[Sqrt[(a^2 h^2 + 2 b^2 k^2 + h^2 k^2 r^2)/(
h^2 (a^2 - k^2 r^2)) - 
2 Sqrt[(a^2 b^2 h^2 k^2 + b^4 k^4 + a^2 h^4 k^2 r^2 + 
  b^2 h^2 k^4 r^2)/(h^4 (a^2 - k^2 r^2)^2)]]] /. r -> 0
```

> 2 ArcTan[Sqrt[(a^2 h^2 + 2 b^2 k^2)/(a^2 h^2) - 
>      2 Sqrt[(a^2 b^2 h^2 k^2 + b^4 k^4)/(a^4 h^4)]]

```
Limit[2 ArcTan[Sqrt[(a^2 h^2 + 2 b^2 k^2 + h^2 k^2 r^2)/(h^2 (a^2 - k^2 r^2)) - 
2 Sqrt[(a^2 b^2 h^2 k^2 + b^4 k^4 + a^2 h^4 k^2 r^2 + 
  b^2 h^2 k^4 r^2)/(h^4 (a^2 - k^2 r^2)^2)]]], r -> a/k, 
Direction -> "FromBelow", Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0 && h > 0 && k > 0]
```

> 0

```
Solve[D[2 ArcTan[
  Sqrt[(a^2 h^2 + 2 b^2 k^2 + h^2 k^2 r^2)/(
   h^2 (a^2 - k^2 r^2)) - 
   2 Sqrt[(a^2 b^2 h^2 k^2 + b^4 k^4 + a^2 h^4 k^2 r^2 + 
     b^2 h^2 k^4 r^2)/(h^4 (a^2 - k^2 r^2)^2)]]], r] == 0 && 
 r > 0 && r < a/k, r, Reals]
```

> {}

Finally, making use of the formula for the area in the generalized polar coordinates
$$Area=\frac {a b} 2 \int\limits_{\phi_1}^{\phi_2} r(\phi)^2 \,d\phi, $$
we find

```
area = 1/2*a*b*Integrate[(a^2 h^2 Cos[\[Phi]]^2 - b^2 k^2 Sin[\[Phi]]^2)/
(h^2 k^2), {\[Phi], -2 ArcTan[Sqrt[(a^2 h^2 + 2 b^2 k^2)/(a^2 h^2) - 
   2 Sqrt[(a^2 b^2 h^2 k^2 + b^4 k^4)/(a^4 h^4)]]], 
2 ArcTan[ Sqrt[(a^2 h^2 + 2 b^2 k^2)/(a^2 h^2) -
2 Sqrt[(a^2 b^2 h^2 k^2 + b^4 k^4)/(a^4 h^4)]]]},
Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0 && k > 0 && h > 0]
```

> a*b*( 1/(4 h^2 k^2)I (2 (a^2 h^2 - 
>         b^2 k^2) (Log[
>          1 - I Sqrt[
>            1 + (2 b k (b k - Sqrt[a^2 h^2 + b^2 k^2]))/(a^2 h^2)]] - 
>         Log[1 + I Sqrt[
>            1 + (2 b k (b k - Sqrt[a^2 h^2 + b^2 k^2]))/(
>             a^2 h^2)]]) + (a^2 h^2 + b^2 k^2) Sinh[
>        2 (Log[1 - 
>             I Sqrt[1 + (2 b k (b k - Sqrt[a^2 h^2 + b^2 k^2]))/(
>               a^2 h^2)]] - 
>           Log[1 + I Sqrt[
>              1 + (2 b k (b k - Sqrt[a^2 h^2 + b^2 k^2]))/(a^2 h^2)]])])

At last but not least, we perform the verification

```
N[area /. {a -> 2, b -> 1, k -> Sqrt[2], h -> Sqrt[3]}]
```

> $2.7885\, +0. i $

Comment: Here are the executed code as PDF file https://www.dropbox.com/s/3wdhtbo8uoswo66/Area.pdf?dl=0 and the executed code as nb file https://www.dropbox.com/s/s0vogn6irqcrogr/Area.nb?dl=0 .

Comment: See https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=14niBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA313&lpg=PA313&dq=generalized+polar+coordinates&source=bl&ots=Dv9fWOkYCL&sig=3celjQPwxavpRyLyEqLVLYY8YmA&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq6LOBqJfaAhVDQpoKHdTwBNo4ChDoAQg2MAI#v=onepage&q=generalized%20polar%20coordinates&f=false concerning the generalized polar coordinates.

Answer (score 6):

The following procedure produces an exact answer. First, use [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate) with [`Boole`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boole) instead of an [`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion):

```
area = Integrate[Boole[(x^2/4+y^2)^2<=x^2/2-y^2/3],{x,0,3}, {y, -1,1}];
area //TeXForm
```

> $\int_0^{2 \sqrt{2}} \frac{\sqrt{-3 x^2+2 \sqrt{21 x^2+1}-2}}{\sqrt{3}} \, dx$

This way we convert your problem into an integration problem. It's a shame Mathematica can't do this integral without help. Anyway, let's do a change of variables. First, inactivate the integral:

```
integral = Inactivate[Evaluate[area], Integrate];
```

Then, do the following change of variables:

```
f[x_] = Sqrt[1+21x^2];
finv[z_] = Sqrt[z^2 - 1]/Sqrt[21];
```

Then, we have:

```
measure = finv'[z]
```

> z/(Sqrt[21] Sqrt[-1 + z^2])

So, the new integral is:

```
new = integral /. 
    Inactive[Integrate][integrand_, {x, x0_, x1_}] :>
    Inactive[Integrate][
        Simplify[integrand measure /. x->finv[z], z>1],
        {z, f[x0], f[x1]}
    ]
```

> Inactive[Integrate][1/21 z Sqrt[(13 - z)/(1 + z)], {z, 1, 13}]

This integral can be done by Mathematica:

```
res = Activate @ new
```

> Sqrt[2/3] + (5 [Pi])/6 - 5/3 ArcSin[1/Sqrt[7]]

Let's check:

```
N[res, 20]
N[Area[r], 20]
```

> 2.7884959811605859754
>
> 2.7884959811605859754

Comment: +1. Thank you. The general case with four parameters is asked.

Comment: The Maple command FunctionAdvisor(branch_cuts,sqrt(-3*x^2+2*sqrt(1+21*x^2)-2),plot=2.); shows the branch cuts along the real axis of $x$. See https://www.dropbox.com/s/yg0a9x6hvtsmj4g/BC.rtf?dl=0 .